# What specs are required for using two external monitors with a Chromebook?

Tags: multiple-monitors, chromebook

I've searched all over Google and StackExchange and haven't found an answer to this.

I know that some Chromebooks only support extending the display to one external monitor and some support extending the display to two external monitors.

What are the hardware requirements to support two external monitors?

Is there a specific processor required? Video card? Etc?

Comment: According to the article below, multiple monitors requires (a) a Chromebook with USB-C support, and (b) an external dock or dongle that brings out multiple HDMI connectors.  https://plugable.com/2015/03/13/chrome-os-multiple-monitor-support/

Comment: I've tested this with Chromebooks with that exact setup and then some. Some work. Some don't.

Comment: Also, that article is 4 years old. In tech terms, ancient. :-) haha